# Making USB device wireless

Tags: usb, wireless, nrf24l01

I need to convert my USB device to a wireless one.

The idea is to create something like USB dongle that connects to the PC and communicates with its counterpart by radio. At the opposite side there should be complementary device into which I would plug existing factory-made USB device in a regular way, with a USB cable.

No USB hub functions needed as I am going to always plug a single device.

Low power consumption at the device's side is important.

It is enough to support only Low Speed USB mode.

The task is indeed overwhelming, so let me start from the most important questions

0. Is the idea viable at all?
1. Is it realistic to implement the above simply by routing raw USB packets without making sense of them?
   Ideally I would like to let MCU receive a packet and generate an interrupt. In the corresponding
   handler I would copy data buffer and pass it to the radio module for transmission. At the device side
   it should be similar except for that I should react on radio module interrupts.
2. The choice of MCU. It should allow my code to access raw USB packets without any limitations such
   as fixed once and for all VID/PID.
   As far as I understand not any MCU with USB support is able to work as a host. Meaning that MCU
   at one end may be different from the MCU at the other end, since 'host' feature is only needed at
   the side of the device.
   Price matters, as always. Would it work with chinese CH559?
3. As to the radio, I was hoping to utilize NRF24L01, however I am not sure if they fit the task.
4. After some rather shallow research I abandoned the idea of BlueTooth connection because it
   would not allow PC to see the device exactly the same way as it sees it when it's connected by cable.
   As a result device drivers would not recognize it. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Do you have control over the design of the device, or do you want a general-purpose wireless bridge for USB?

Comment: I have no control of the device. Ideally it should be general-purpose wireless bridge.

Comment: However it is enough to support Low Speed usb mode

Comment: I think you’re going to struggle if you want to cover any significant distance because of the timing constraints of USB.  I see that USB-over-CAT-5 devices exist; if these IP protocol then there’s a possibility you could use a wifi bridge, but I wonder if it would be easier to place a lightweight USB host alongside the device and then exchange data between that and the PC?

Comment: But for this to work I will need to reverse engineer device protocol, right?

Comment: It depends what the USB device is; if it’s something fairly standard then you may well be able to use library code.  In the other hand if you’re trying to make a proprietary dongle look like it’s attached to your PC when it isn’t then you have some work to do.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to convert my USB device to a wireless one.

Tough. USB is a bidirectional thing, and has very tight timing requirements, in the low single-digit microseconds.

Almost universally, just putting a USB-capable host next to the wired USB device will be easier, and then just sending the application data over the wireless link.

Anyway, *wireless USB* does exist, it just isn't that prevalent because it hasn't proven that useful; it's a ultrawideband technology that could transport USB2.

> Low power consumption at the device's side is important.

Bad luck, your device needs to reply to regular USB host requests wirelessly – several hundred times a second.

It's almost certainly more power efficient to put the USB host at the USB device, and just communicate the application data, again.

> Is it realistic to implement the above simply by routing raw USB packets without making sense of them? Ideally I would like to let MCU receive a packet and generate an interrupt. In the corresponding handler I would copy data buffer and pass it to the radio module for transmission. At the device side it should be similar except for that I should react on radio module interrupts.

Not completely, no. You need to handle a few bus organizational things.

Also, an MCU will be too slow to react for this to work, you'll need application-specific logic hardware – an FPGA that you program yourself, or an ASIC.

So, I don't think this is feasible for you, to be honest.

> The choice of MCU.

Doesn't matter, MCU isn't viable.

> As to the radio, I was hoping to utilize NRF24L01, however I am not sure if they fit the task.

Completely, utterly, off. Latency too high, data rate too low, needs to be part of your custom logic.

> After some rather shallow research I abandoned the idea of BlueTooth connection because it would not allow PC to see the device exactly the same way as it sees it when it's connected by cable. As a result device drivers would not recognize it. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

The problem with Bluetooth is not that, but that as a protocol it doesn't allow for the necessary timings.

Comment: They have WiFi client dongles which are wireless USB, I have one. “  wireless USB does exist ?”

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 yes, it does. There's a standard called "[wireless USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_USB)".

Comment: Do the timing requirements hold for low speed mode?

Comment: yes, they do; it's USB.

Answer (score 1):

If both sides have access to the internet or to a wifi network, another option would be to run a USB server on a small computer (eg. Raspberry Pi, smartphone or a specialized USB server hub), to which the devices connect, with a client on the remote machine that creates a virtual USB device.

I can't recommend a particular software but a search for "USB server" suggests some options.